# Linear dependence with homogeneous 3rd order DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

I am trying to figure out if this equation is solvable. I was given

$$ y^{(3)} + 3y^{''} - 10y^{'} = 0 $$

with initial conditions

$$ y(0)=7, y'(0)=0, y''(0)=70. $$

I solved the characteristic equation and ended up with m = -5, m = 0, m = 2. Then I found that the general solution was

$$ y = c_1e^{-5t}+c_2+c_3e^{2t}. $$

But when I find the Wronskian to determine linear independence, I end up with

$$ W = 
    \det\begin{pmatrix}
    e^{-5t} & 1 & e^{2t} \\
    -5e^{-5t} & 0 & 2e^{2t} \\
    25e^{-5t} & 0 & 4e^{2t} \\
    \end{pmatrix} = 0.
$$
Does this mean that $y$ is not a viable solution?

EDIT: Removed $y = y^{(3)}...$

Comment: I am confused by your first equation: if you take the left hand side and the right hand side, ignoring the middle, you get $y=0$.

Comment: @Andrei Removed the $y=...$, that was a typo

Comment: I get the Wronskian is $70e^{-3t}$. How did you get zero?

Comment: @InterstellarProbe Just double checked my work, I had an error finding the determinant. You're correct.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: By using the substitution $v=y'$ the equation becomes a second order ODE
$$v''+3v'-10v=0$$
which has an auxiliary equation of
$$m^2+3m-10=0$$
$$(m+5)(m-2)=0$$
$$m=-5, 2$$
$$\therefore v=y'=c_1e^{-5t}+c_2e^{2t}$$ 
$$y=\int c_1e^{-5t}+c_2e^{2t} dt = c_3e^{-5t}+c_4e^{2t}+c_5$$
$$y(0)=c_3+c_4+c_5=7$$
$$y'(0)=-5c_3+2c_4+c_5=0$$
$$y''(0)=25c_3+4c_4+c_5=70$$
$$\therefore \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ -5 & 2 & 1 \\ 25 & 4 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} c_3\\ c_4 \\ c_5\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 7\\ 0\\ 70\end{pmatrix}$$
$$\begin{pmatrix} c_3\\ c_4 \\ c_5\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ -5 & 2 & 1 \\ 25 & 4 & 1\end{pmatrix}^{-1}\begin{pmatrix} 7\\ 0\\ 70\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 5 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$$